# how to change an object to array in postman in order to solve "TypeError: tasks.map is not a function"

Tags: node.js, multer

im creating a api that should upload a image with multer but im getting tasks.map is not a function, here is the code:

```
router.post('/',uploads.any(), async (req, res) => {

    try{
        const { title, description, tasks } = req.body

        const project =  await Project.create({title, description, user: req.userId });
       
        console.log(req.body)
       await Promise.all(tasks.map( async task => {
            const projectTask = new Task({...task, project: project._id})

           await projectTask.save()

           project.tasks.push(projectTask)
        }))

        await project.save()
        return res.send({ project })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(400).send({error: 'Error creating new project'})
        
       
    }
})
```

my console.log for the req.body is this :

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  title: 'titulo',
  description: 'tinha feito errado',
  tasks: [Object: null prototype] {
    title: 'testee form',
    descriptiom: 'tomara que funcione',
    dicionario: [Object: null prototype] { nome: 'Teste' },
    assignedTo: '605df6eab581542e58d447ac'
  }
}
```

how you can see it is an object but I need it to be an array, how can I solve this?

and here is my request:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tasks` object is not an array (as you can see in the `console.log()`), so you can not use `map` on it.

If you want to send it as an array, try to send data in Postman like this:

```
tasks[0][title]
tasks[0][description]
...
```

So, just add `[0]` after the `tasks`.